# Server ignoring latest JDK version

Tags: java

`C:\Program Files\Java` contains 3 directories:

- jdk1.8.0_74
- jdk-11.0.2
- jre1.8.0_201

Yet the java.exe process I find running is that of `\jdk1.8.0_74\bin`

Why is it not using the latest version, and how can I force it to do so?

Comment: Uninstall the older ones?

Comment: Depends on how the process is getting launched.  We'd need more detail to be able to assist.

Comment: @HarryJohnston it is launched through the NewAtlanta servlet container. I tried uninstalling older versions and even NA wouldn't launch. It seems it *needs* jdk1.8.0_74.

Comment: You mean New Atlanta's ServletExec?  It may need to be configured to tell it which JRE to use.  Check the documentation.  If you can't figure out how to reconfigure it, you might have better luck asking on their support forums than here.